# icons in all of programs are very small (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, display-settings

I tried several times and asked many of friends to solve this problem but unfortunately we could not.

When I open any program in my laptop, the ribbon icons very small and it is extremely difficult to know each icon.

Is there any suggested solution to solve this problem please?

Here is a screen shot of Photoshop program on my Laptop.

[image: screenshot of desktop/icons]

Comment: Taskbar & Startmenu properties -> Use small icons?

Comment: Why does that image look flipped?

Answer (score 6):

Based on a solution found on the [Lenovo Forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Some-of-my-programs-are-very-small/td-p/3520124), I partly solved this problem by:

1. Right click on application shortcut and select *Properties*.
   [image]
2. Select the *Compatibility* tab.
   [image]
3. Press *Change high DPI settings* button.
4. Check *Override high DPI scaling behavior* and choose *System* or *System (Enhanced)*.
   [image]

As mentioned in the [original solution](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Some-of-my-programs-are-very-small/td-p/3520124), there are still some minor issues (for me - small mouse cursor in some areas) but this solved my problem with small icons.

Answer (score 3):

#### When I open any program in my laptop, the taskbar icons are very small

Use the following procedure to change the taskbar icon size:

> 1. Right-click on an empty space on the desktop.
> 2. Select Display settings from the contextual menu.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Move the slider under "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100%, 125%, 150%, or 175%.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Hit Apply at the bottom of the settings window. Windows might ask you to log out and log back in for a more consistent experience.
>
> This will not only make the icons in the taskbar a bit larger, but it
>   will also make text bigger in apps like Microsoft Edge and Calendar,
>   as well as in Windows 10 notification windows.

Source [How to Change the Icon Size in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/change-icon-size-windows-10)

Comment: unfortunately this way did not work with me.

Comment: Slider does not appear for me.